# PHPMailer - Formatação no Email

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Estou com um problema de formatação quando o email chega na caixa de entrada.

Aqui está o código do HTML:

```
$mensagem = "
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td>Nome:</td><td>$name</td></tr>
<tr><td>E-mail:</td><td>$email</td></tr>
<tr><td>Telefone:</td><td>$phone</td></tr>
<br>
<h4>Qual a melhor forma de pagamento se encaixa no perfil da sua empresa:</h4>
<tr><td>Dinheiro:</td><td>$dinheiro</td></tr>
<tr><td>Débito:</td><td>$debito</td></tr>
<tr><td>Crédito:</td><td>$credito</td></tr>
<tr><td>Voucher:</td><td>$voucher</td></tr>
<tr><td>Eletrônico:</td><td>$eletronico</td></tr>
<tr><td>Outros:</td><td>$outros1</td></tr>
<tr><td>Outros-Texto:</td><td>$outros_1</td></tr>
<br>
<h4>Que tipo de carro supre suas necessidades:</h4>
<tr><td>PCD:</td><td>$pcd</td></tr>
<tr><td>Luxo:</td><td>$luxo</td></tr>
<tr><td>Perua Grande:</td><td>$perua</td></tr>
<tr><td>Todos acima:</td><td>$todos</td></tr>
<br>
<h4>Qual a melhor forma de pagamento se encaixa no perfil da sua empresa:</h4>
<tr><td>Despesa com táxi:</td><td>$despesataxi</td></tr>
<tr><td>Rastreamento em tempo real:</td><td>$rastreal</td></tr>
<tr><td>Autonomia para inclusão e exclusão de corridas autorizadas:</td><td>$autonomia</td></tr>
<tr><td>Agendamento de táxi:</td><td>$agentaxi</td></tr>
<tr><td>Tempo de espera:</td><td>$tempespera</td></tr>
<tr><td>Estimativa de valor:</td><td>$estivalor</td></tr>
<tr><td>Envio de documentos e encomendas:</td><td>$enviodoc</td></tr>
<tr><td>Outros:</td><td>$outros2</td></tr>
<tr><td>Outros-Texto:</td><td>$outros_2</td></tr>
<br>
<h4>Como você gostaria de solicitar um táxi:</h4>
<tr><td>Call Center:</td><td>$callcenter</td></tr>
<tr><td>WhatsApp:</td><td>$whats</td></tr>
<tr><td>CHAT:</td><td>$chat</td></tr>
<tr><td>APP:</td><td>$app</td></tr>
<tr><td>Portal Web:</td><td>$portalweb</td></tr>
<tr><td>Outros:</td><td>$outros3</td></tr>
<tr><td>Outros-Texto:</td><td>$outros_3</td></tr>
<br>
<h4>Mensagem:</h4>
<tr><td>Informações adicionais:</td><td>$infoadc</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>";
```

Config PHPMail

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "xxxx";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xxx";
$mail->Password = "xxx";
$mail->SMTPDebug = false;
$mail->setFrom('xxx');
$mail->addAddress('xxx', 'Contato |xx');
$mail->Subject = 'xxx - Pesquisa: Solução Tecnológica';
$mail->addCC('xxx@email', 'Cópia Djalma');
$mail->addBCC('xxx@email', 'Cópia Oculta');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Priority = 3;
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->msgHTML( $mensagem );
$mail->AltBody = strip_tags( $mensagem );
```

No email está chegando assim: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser? Sendo era para as informações estarem em baixo de cada .

**OBS:** Somente no Gmail chega o email "tudo ok".
Outlook ou semelhantes tudo desconfigurado.

Comment: Vc não pode colocar as tags <h4> fora das colunas <td> da tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está na formatação da sua tabela. Aqui por exemplo:

```
<tr><td>Telefone:</td><td>$phone</td></tr>
<br>
<h4>Qual a melhor forma de pagamento se encaixa no perfil da sua empresa:</h4>
<tr><td>Dinheiro:</td><td>$dinheiro</td></tr>
```

note que a quebra de linha `<br>` está fora de uma linha/coluna
O mesmo para o `<h4>`

Coloque esses parametros corretamente:

```
<tr>
    <td>Telefone:</td>
    <td>$phone</td></tr>

<!-- colspan="2" faz a sua coluna ocupar 2 espaços como se fosse uma linha só -->

 <tr> 
    <td colspan="2> 
       <h4>Qual a melhor forma de pagamento se encaixa no perfil da sua empresa:</h4> 
    </td>
 </tr>


<tr>
    <td>Dinheiro:</td>
    <td>$dinheiro</td>
</tr>
```

Repita esse mesmo processo para as demais ocorrências